# angular and select - setting the default value

Tags: angularjs

I am struggling trying to set the default value of a select box from a value in the controller.

my controller has

```
controller.item = {name: "bar1", value:1}
controller.items = [{name: "bar0", value:0},{name: "bar1", value:1}]
```

my html is

```
<p>{{controller.item}}</p>
<select ng-model="controller.item" ng-options="item.name for item in controller.items" >
</select>
```

when i run the code, the correct value of controller.item is shown in the form

{"name": "bar1", "value": 1}

but the select box has the first entry showing (bar0)

what am I missing here ? I've looked on the web, but all the examples I've seen say that you must do

```
controller.item = controller.items[0]
```

however, that's not right for the scenario where the value is already set

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your notation Angular is trying to match `item.name` with your entire `item` object.

```
item to match: {name: "bar1", value:1}
value to match againist: 'bar1'

'bar1' != {name: "bar1", value:1} // Nothing selected by default since no matching ocurrs
```

In order to do the match correctly you should try using [the complete ng-optons notation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions):

```
<select ng-model="controller.item" ng-options="item as item.name for item in controller.items"></select>
```

Here you'll be defining `controller.item` as your **model** and it will check with the **entire item object** in your ng-options but be **labeled as** `item.name` *(since you defined it in the ng-options declaration)*, so your select will render your objects *name* property as *options*, and not the entire object, but it will do the matching againist the entire object

Answer (score 1):

Your `ngOptions` is a bit off, the syntax is `value as text for item in array` - so set the value to `item`

```
<select ng-model="controller.item" ng-options="item as item.name for item in controller.items" >
</select>
```

And to default:

```
controller.items = [{name: "bar0", value:0},{name: "bar1", value:1}]
controller.item = controller.items[0];
```

Comment: sorry, that was a typo on my part. I do have

item as item.name for item in controller.items 

I don't want to default the select to the initial entry - I want the select to show the current value of controller.item, not to set controller.item to the first item in the array ;)

Comment: @jmls -- The value in the `select` has to be available inside the `ngOptions` array - it can't be an unknown

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<p>{{item}}</p>
<select ng-model="item" ng-options="item.name for item in items" >
</select>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('MainCtlr',function($scope){
  var selected = 0;
  $scope.items = [
    {name: "bar0", value:0},
    {name: "bar1", value:1}
  ];
  $scope.item = $scope.items[selected];
});
```

When you set a default option in a `ng-options` directive, must be by reference. You can't create a new object. The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) says:

> By default, ngModel watches the model by reference, not value

http://codepen.io/ces/pen/jPxBZz

Comment: thanks - but I don't want to default the select to the fist entry in the array - I want the select to show the current value of controller.item

Comment: The default option must be a element of the `ng-options` array.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is `controller.item` is not the same as `controller.items[1]`.

I'm sure someone could expand upon why that is way better than I could but it has to do with comparing objects in JavaScript.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript) is a link to another post for that.

What you're going to want to do is find the object you want in the array  and set that to controller.item.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var controller = this;
  var tempItem = {name: "bar1", value:1};
  controller.items = [{name: "bar0", value:0},{name: "bar1", value:1}]

  for(var i = 0; i < controller.items.length; i++){
    if(controller.items[i].name == tempItem.name) {
      controller.item = controller.items[i];
    }
  }
});
```

You can achieve the same effect with the amazingly amazing library [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#) like this.

```
controller.item = _.findWhere(controllerItems,{name: tempItem.name});
```

[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OQmpf6QAQGjORoAuPpvJ?p=preview)

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the `selected` attribute to the corresponding `option` element within the `select`

Comment: Won't work Angular `ngOptions` - there aren't any `option` tags.